# Loading Images in background while not locking the files

Tags: wpf, multithreading, image

My application loads a lot of images in a BackgroundWorker to stay usable. My Image control is bound to a property named "ImageSource". If this is null it's loaded in the background and raised again.

```
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (imageSource != null)
            {
                return imageSource;
            }

            if (!backgroundImageLoadWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundImageLoadWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
                backgroundImageLoadWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                    new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
                backgroundImageLoadWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            return imageSource;
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        try
        {
              bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
              bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 300;

              MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
              byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
              memoryStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
              memoryStream.Position = 0;
              bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;                            

         }
         finally
         {
             bitmap.EndInit();
         }
        bitmap.Freeze();
        e.Result = bitmap;
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmap = e.Result as BitmapSource;

        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                (ThreadStart)delegate()
                {
                    imageSource = bitmap;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
                }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
        }
    }
```

This is all well so far but my users can change the images in question. They choose a new image in an OpenDialog, the old image file is overwritten with the new and ImageSource is raised again which loads the new image with the same filename again:

```
    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return imagePath; }
        set
        {
            imagePath= value;
            imageSource = null;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }
    }
```

On some systems the overwriting of the old file results in an exception:

```
    "a generic error occured in GDI+" and "The process cannot access the file..."
```

I tried a lot of things like loading with BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache and BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad. This raised Exceptions when loading them:

```
   Key cannot be null.
   Parameter name: key
```

If I try this without the BackgroundWorker on the UI thread it works fine. Am I doing something wrong? Isn't it possible to load the images in the background while keeping the files unlocked?

Comment: Please post your "This leads to a new call to ImageSource which loads the new image with the same filename again".  Why are you loading again.  Why don't you just use the image you have and overwrite the file?

Comment: @BalamBalam This is really just calling RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource") again after setting a new (or existing) file path. If I don't load the ImageSource again and only copy the file the change is not visible in the UI and the error still occurs. As far as I understand it the error happens when copying the new file because my app locked the file for the cache.

Comment: Why set imageSource = null; and RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource"); ?  Could you not just load the user specified file to imageSource, RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource") (where it will use imageSource since it is not null), and then use a background thread to File.WriteAllBytes ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this lead to similar exceptions. I have a solution now to this house made problem of mine (see answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems all of the above works. I simplified the example for the question and somehow on the way lost the problem.

The only difference I could see in my code is that the loading of the image itself was delegated to a specific image loader class which somehow created the problem. When I removed this dependency the errors disappeared.